# An inequality involving homogeneous polynomials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials, holder-inequality, jensen-inequality

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots x_k \ge 0$ be non-negative real numbers.

Does it follow that
$$k \left( \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^3 \right)^2 \ge \left( \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2 \right)^3 ? $$

This seems like something that might easily follow from standard inequalities like Jensen's inequality?

(Now I am embarrassed that I hadn't really carefully tried Jensen before asking. As a penance, I will post a solution using Jensen's inequality.)

Comment: It does follow from Jensen. Have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Holder $$k\left(\sum_{i=1}^kx_i^3\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^k1\left(\sum_{i=1}^kx_i^3\right)^2\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^k\sqrt[3]{1\cdot\left(x_i^3\right)^2}\right)^{1+2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^kx_i^2\right)^3.$$

Answer (score 1):

- Using Holder, $$\sum_{i=1}^kx_i^2\leq k^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^kx_i^3\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}.$$
- Jensen also works with the convex function $x\mapsto x^\frac{3}{2}$, what gives $$\left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kx_i^3.$$

Answer (score 1):

In case it is helpful for anyone else, I will post another solution using Jensen's inequality.

Jensen's inequality says that for a convex function $\phi$, numbers in its domain $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_k$, and positive weights $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k$, we have 
$$\phi \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i y_i }{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i} \right) \le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \phi(y_i) }{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i}.$$

Set $a_i = 1$ and $y_i = x_i^2$ for $i=1, 2, \dots k $, and let $\phi(x) = x^{3/2}$. Then we have
$$\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2 }{k} \right)^{3/2} \le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^3 }{k}.$$
Squaring both sides gives the desired result.

Comment: Your solution is very similar to my second solution.

Comment: Yes, I guess I was figuring it out and typing it as you were posting yours, and didn't see that you had already posted a Jensen solution.

Answer (score 0):

Also, we can use Jensen here.

Indeed, let $x_i^2=a_i$.
Thus, by Jensen for the convex function $f(x)=x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ we obtain:
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^ka_i^{\frac{3}{2}}}{k}\geq\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^ka_i}{k}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}},$$ which is our inequality exactly!